# Cannot adjust screen brightness (Samsung laptop on Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, display, ubuntu-12.04

None of the answers in [this same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252628/cant-adjust-screen-brightness-on-ubuntu-12-04lts) worked for me. Does anyone have another solution?

The problem is that in reboot screen goes back to 100 per cent bright.

Comment: perhaps you could somehow automate keypresses eg Fn+F2, or automate the move to  change the setting. but it might stil be bright for a moment, I haven't tried it.  or you could get a vinyl sheet http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1193925   neutral density filter http://solargraphicshome.com/Neutral_Density_Film.html

Comment: I tried this http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-save-screen-brightness-settings-in-ubuntu-12-04-laptop#comment-19226 and so far it works.

Comment: you can post that as an answer, answering your own question, and accept it